# Прогресс бар для каждого загружаемого файла

Tags: javascript, ajax, formdata

Пытаюсь реализовать загрузку файлов на сервер. Файлы успешно отправляются с помощью объекта FormData. Хочу добавить прогресс бар для каждого загружаемого файла и общий. Сделать общий получается, отслеживая событие progress, а для каждого файла - нет. Как это можно сделать, если все файлы отправляются одним запросом? Или необходимо делать несколько запросов, отправляя в одном запросе по одному файлу?

```
var nf_button = document.getElementById("new-homework");
nf_button.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var files = nf_button.files;
    var formData = new FormData();
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
         formData.append('file', files[i]);
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', /upload_file);
    request.send(formData);

    request.onprogress = function () {
        processBar();  //ф-я успешно реализует общий прогресс бар
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Посылая файлы одним запросом можно отслеживать прогресс всего запроса, но не отдельного файла. Если вам необходимо отслеживать загрузку каждого файла, то посылайте каждый файл отдельно, но учтите, что тогда, скорее всего, придется создавать некую точку сохранения состояния, чтобы знать к чему привязать картинку и избежать повторений (например, если картинка грузится при создании поста, и в форм дате передается еще текст поста, то при каждой отдельной загрузке файла будет создаваться новый пост).